# Upgrading 2.x to 3.x With Task Methods which end in -Async for Asp.Net Boilerplate

Tags: xmlhttprequest, aspnetboilerplate

I have found that my legacy services which have a method name that follows:

> public Task SomeMethodNameAsync(...)

Has the API signature

> service.someMethodName(...)

for the UI to make XHR requests to.  Essentially, the upgrade is forcing us to change ALL of our APIs which have that signature.

My question is whether this is a documented feature, or, if there is a flag somewhere (which I haven't found via Google) for disabling this renaming of the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature is listed as a breaking change in [v3.2.0](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/releases/tag/v3.2.0).

It doesn't change the actual endpoint for XHR requests, just the jQuery proxy.

To disable the renaming, configure this in the `PreInitialize` method of your `*.Web.Core` module:

```cs
Configuration.Modules.AbpWebCommon().ApiProxyScripting.RemoveAsyncPostfixOnProxyGeneration = false;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked as described!  I need to go back and practice my google-fu :(